# Goals dialog not populated

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-dms

Sitecore 6.6 Update 4

I've got an instance of Sitecore that is having an issue with goals.  After creating (and publishing) goals, I try to assign the goal to a specific content item.  When I click on the 'Analyze\Attributes\Goals' button in the ribbon, the dialog is presented, but no goals are populated in the box.

I've looked at my error logs and don't see any errors.  I've watched via Fiddler and don't see anything.  I've used Chrome's developer tools and see no errors.

I have another instance of Sitecore running on the same server and it has no issues populating the goals dialog box.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, thanks to Mark (+1) for pointing me down a direction for solving this.  This has to do with automating analytics deployment on CD servers.

Looking at section 6.2.1 of the [ECM Administrator and Developers Guide](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/products/ecm/210/ecm_administrator_and_developer_guide_21-usletter.pdf), you can see that there are two tasks:

1. Adding the Auto Publish action
2. Updating the Web.config with a workflow provider for the default definition database

The goals were associated with the "Analytics Workflow", but they weren't going into a draft state after creating them and they weren't being properly deployed when saving.

After ensuring that the steps from the ECM dev guide were followed in the client's CM/CD environments, everything started working again.

Note: this may not be something someone normally sees with a default install.  I had begun the process of implementing the ECM autopublish by editing the web.config files and had not completed the process of adding the "auto publish" action.  Once I ensured that all items were correct, the process worked as expected.

Comment: Can you add the following attribute for your 'shell' site definition in web.config (sitecore/sites/site[@name='shell']):
analyticsDefinitions="content". I think I met this problem before and I resolved it with this small change

Answer (score 3):

Likely your goals have not been deployed to your Analytics dataset. Try pointing SQL Management Studio to your Analytics Database and issue the following:

```
SELECT *
  FROM [Sitecore_analytics].[dbo].[PageEventDefinitions]
```

And make sure that the goals you are registering are actually present here. There should be a Guid in PageEventDefinitionId that matches the Sitecore Item ID of your Goal.

Comment: Actually. I might have misread your question - my proposed fix will help if registered goals are not showing in any reports, but I think you're experiencing a problem much earlier on in the process

Comment: Thanks Mark!  While I think you're right regarding this applying to reports, I do think you're on to something. (or have at least provided something else to investigate)  When I look in the PageEventDefintions table, the newly-created goals are not there.  All the 'OOTB' goals are there, however.  Will do some additional testing with the 'working' instance to see if they show up in that table immediately.

Comment: After verifying with the 'working' instance, I can say that the goal shows up in that table immediately.  Looking into why it's not showing up there now for the 'broken' instance.